# Membership reporting

Tags: custom-reports

Thank you first off for the added features and seemingly easier access to data for Team Dirt in Oregon. I am attempting to adjust the report to include the e-mails for members and also would love to pre-sort the Elapsed and Canceled members. I am struggling with only finding a way to create or add the e-mail to the report. Also most records have 3-4 entries per Member which makes the report cluttered.

Thanks

Comment: What CMS is CiviCRM running on (Drupal, Wordpress, etc.) and what version of CiviCRM is installed?

Can you please post the URL of the report you are modifying (i.e. /civicrm/report/instance/1 ) ? or the name of the report? A screenshot showing some sample data/replicating your issue would be invaluable.

Comment: Also who is your provider or are you self hosting?